# Solving equation with convolution

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, math, inverse-problem

I have the measured signal $y(t)$ that can be modeled in the frequency domain as $Y(f)$:

$$Y(f) = X(f)\cdot A(f) - [X(f)\cdot B(f)] \ast C(f)$$

where $\ast$ is the convolution.
I know $A(f)$, $B(f)$, and $C(f)$. I measure $Y(f)$. Is there a way to retrieve $X(f)$?
I know that if $C(f)$ is constant and $1$, then I can easily retrieve $X(f)$ except for frequencies with $A(f)=B(f)$.
But how do I go about this for an arbitrary but known $C(f)$?

Comment: What's the order of operation? Is it $[X(f) \cdot B(f)]*C(f)$ or $X(f) \cdot [B(f)*C(f)]$

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. What is the [associativity](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/59221/15892)?

Comment: First $X(f)B(f)$, then the convolution.